# how to replace quotation marks with \"

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

im trying to echo mediaplayer embed code with IF statement. is there any way to replace all quotation marks (") with (\")'s ?

thank you..

Comment: The answer to that kind of depends on whether you just want to escape quotation marks, or all special characters recognized by `addslashes`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As comments and other answers indicate your question may not be quite explicit enough. Taking it at face value, if you just want to replace double quotes (`"`) you should use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace('"', '\"', $string);
```

Answer (score 5):

[`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) will do the trick.

It will return a new string with the all the quotes ( `'` **and** `"` ) with their escaped counterparts.